# Share raw file via Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I want to share an audio file which is stored into raw folder via Bluetooth, whenever i am trying to share getting : ***File not sent***

```
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.rock_band);
    String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.rock_band;
    Log.d("filePath::--", uri);
    Intent intent = new Intent();   
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
        "com.android.bluetooth",
        "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
    intent.setType("audio/mp3");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Manifest permissions:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

please let me know where i am doing mistake.

and **log** says:-

```
   D/filePath::--(1663): android.resource://com.productions.music/2131034112
```